# Java hashtable occurence number

Tags: java, hashtable

Hello, please I have a problem understanding the Hash table.
I just read that it is a table with key and value.
Here I will calculate the occurrence number of each word in the file.
It works but I didn't understand the logic behind it and how the hashtable works here, any help, please?

```
         String st;   
         HashMap<String, Integer> wordCountTable = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
         try {
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String uniqueWord = st.toLowerCase();
                //System.out.println(uniqueWord);
                Integer count = wordCountTable.get(uniqueWord);

                {
                    if(count != null) {

                        count ++; }
                    else
                        count = 1;  
                    wordCountTable.put(uniqueWord, count);
```

Comment: A hash table is basically an array where the elements are indexed by things other than integers -- strings in this case.  `wordCountTable.put("abcde", 5)` creates a new entry in the table called "abcde", which has the value 5.  When I say `wordCountTable.get("abcde")`, I get back 5.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: I get this point, but what is weird for me here is that I calculate the occurrence number of each word in my file, and the code [ if else ] I don't get how it works. I have the right result but the logic I didn't get it.

Comment: You get each word, one at a time.  If the word already exists in the table (so `wordCountTable.get` has a number), then we add 1 to the number and update the table.  If the word does not exist in the table (so `wordCountTable.get` returns `null`), then we create a new entry with the value 1.

Comment: what cant understand, can't find the part of the code that checks the existence of the word.

Comment: @isi the part of the code that checks the existence of the word is what Tim Roberts posted, `Integer count = wordCountTable.get(uniqueWord);`. If the table does not have an entry for the word, it will return `null`.

Comment: here the entry is the key or I'm wrong?

Comment: And how it calcul the occurrence number then ?

Comment: An entry is the key and its value together. If there is no entry in the map for a given key, then `get` will return `null`. In your code, that means if `count` is `null`, then you have not encountered the current word yet, so you `put` a **new** entry into the map with a value of `1`. Otherwise, if `count` is not `null`, then you _have_ encountered the current word at least once, and you **replace** that entry (via `put`) with a value of `count + 1`.

Comment: That if-else may be a little too clever for its own good. An equivalent that may be more understandable to you is: `if (count == null) { wordCountTable.put(uniqueWord, 1); } else { wordCountTable.put(uniqueWord, count + 1); }`.

Comment: As an aside, the `get`, if-else, and `put` could be simplified to `wordCountTable.merge(uniqueWord, 1, Integer::sum)` (see [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) and read up on functional interfaces/lambda expressions/method references if you want to know more).

Comment: yeah it's clever to compare with if and here count has the value not the key but we need to compare with the key (the word), it's hard to understand but it works

Comment: @Slaw I would suggest using `Math::addExact` rather than `Integer::sum` although in this instance the chance of an overflow may be small.

Comment: @isi The key is always `uniqueWord`, which changes as lines are read from the file (i.e., as the `while` loop iterates). The map knows which value is mapped with which key and returns the correct value (or `null` if no value currently exists) for each key (i.e., word).

Answer (score 1):

> *"... how the hashtable works here, any help, please?"*

To clarify, there is the *[Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html)* class, and the *[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html)* class.
The *HashMap* class is newer, being from the *[Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/package-summary.html)*.

Here is a summary of the code.

Get the current *value* of *key*, *uniqueWord*.

```java
count = wordCountTable.get(uniqueWord)
```

If the *value* is *null*, the *key* does not exist in the map.
Thus, increment by *1*, or start at *1*.

```java
if(count != null) {

    count ++; }
else
    count = 1;
```

Add or replace *key* *uniqueWord*, with *value* *count*.

```java
wordCountTable.put(uniqueWord, count)
```

Additionally, this code can be simplified with with the *[merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction))* method.

```java
Map<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();
try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""))) {
    String w;
    while ((w = r.readLine()) != null) m.merge(w, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean by that, that the same words have all the same value in coding the save key has the same value, or how?

Comment: No need for an `if` statement or `putIfAbsent`, just use `merge`.

Comment: @isi, the _[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)_ _interface_ uses a _[Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)_ for the _keys_.  The _String_ "abc" will increment independently of "ABC".